# Is there a way to monitor which file an application is reading from?

Tags: windows

An application is refusing to open because I've messed with it's settings. I've deleted and reinstalled the application but I'm pretty sure the settings are saved somewhere else. Now if I can locate and delete this settings file, the application should run like new.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you delete or uninstall the program? What you want to do is uninstalling. You could try to run CCleaner afterwards to remove orphaned registry entries